# Find a matrix $A$, such that the following function is a solution to a $2\times 2$ differential equation system.

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

**Exercise :**

> Find the matrix $A$, such that the following function is a solution to a $2\times 2$ differential equation system :
>
> $$x(t) = \begin{bmatrix} e^{-t}(\cos t + 2\sin t) \\ e^{-t}\cos t \end{bmatrix}$$

**Attempt :**

I understand we need the following :

$$\begin{bmatrix} x_1' \\ x_2' \end{bmatrix} = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
a & b  \\
c & d \end{array} \right) \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} $$

so we get the system :

$$\begin{cases} x_1' = ax_1 + bx_2 \\ x_2' = cx_1 + dx_2\end{cases}$$

which translates to :

$$\begin{cases} x_1' = a[e^{-t}(\cos t + 2\sin t)] + b e^{-t}\cos t \\ x_2' = c[e^{-t}(\cos t + 2\sin t)] + d e^{-t}\cos t\end{cases}$$

but this leads me in a $2\times 2$ system whilst having $4$ variables to find.

I seem to be a little stuck on this problem, so I would really appreciate some hints/tips or a solution. This is an exercise that is part of a chapter involving stability and stationary points, so maybe there's a way to work through them to calculate the matrix $A$ ? I tried checking it by eye but didn't see anything.

I would really appreciate any help !

Comment: Replace $x'_1$ and $x'_2$ on the left-hand side of your last displayed equation by the terms that you get from the known solution (e.g., $x_2'(t)=-e^{-t}[\sin(t)+\cos(t)]$). Then collect terms with equal $t$-functions and compare their coefficients on the left-hand sides and the right-hand sides. This should give your four (linear) equations for the four unknown parameters.

Comment: @GerhardS. Yeah I'm dumb, haha, too tired ! Thanks a lot for opening my eyes !